# How to add comment line in AWS Athena query editor

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

It very simple but feel not possible. Do you know how to add comment line in Athena query editor

Comment: It was my browser temporry issue. -- was not work for that time. anyway answer is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add single line comments using prefix "`--`"

Example -

```
--This is a comment
SELECT * FROM data_cat.example
```